# Using all variables in a module, except for one - is there an opposite of "only"?

Tags: fortran

I have a module with global variables, there are a lot of variables in it. For a specific subroutine I would like to use all variables in it except for 1.

One way I could do this is

```
use Global_Variables, only : item1,...item50,item52,...item100
```

but that is incredibly painful to write out 99 items to use, just so in this example I can skip item51.

I could also put this specific item in a seperate `Global_Variables2` module, but that is unwieldy.

Is there an `except` clause that can be used similarly but oppositely of the `only` clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rename the variable to something that obviously should not be used

```
 use mod, disabled => item
```

There is no except in  Fortran 2008. Also think if that variable really needs to be public.

Comment: It is for trouble shooting purpose. I will just comment it out in Global_Variables and pass it around. There is just a lot of subroutines to pass it too. And other variables I may have to repeat the task with. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You do not have to comment it out, you can also make it private. But the amount of work is similar.